# predicate for querying a substring of a string from coredata

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate, nsfilemanager

In my project i have a set of attributes in an entity.One of them is path as string.I want all the records which has my string as a subpath in the path.

Example:
**Path:**/var/mobile/Applications/C4ECC129-36D2-4428-8BB0-  6B1F4C971FC1/Library/Caches/Packages/1000

**Mystring** : Library/Caches/Packages/1000

I tried using Like and contains as below but failed.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bookPath like[c] '%%%@'",Mystring];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bookPath Contains[cd] '%@'",Mystring];
```

Can some one help in writing the predicate to fetch those records which contains mystring.

Really helps me a lot.

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to have a predicate like this

```
[fecthRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bookPath endswith[cd] %@", myString]];
```

or this

```
[fecthRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bookPath contains[cd] %@", myString]];
```

The no results is due to single quotes around your `%@`. From the documentation ([Dynamic Property Names](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-208600)):

> string variables are surrounded by quotation marks when they are
>   substituted into a format string using %@

About the predicates I really suggest to use the first, if the sub-path you are looking for it is always in the final part of the original path.

About using predicates, I really suggest to read [String Comparisons](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains %@", @"bookPath", Mystring];
```

Comment: i tried but experienced a crash with log as:Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11. Can u plz help if you have any idea